# Passing Global Options to line Chart in 2.1.6/Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Here is my jsfiddle explaining the issue I am facing. I want to basically pass the options object (to disable fill and bezier curves) like I could have done in the older versions...

https://jsfiddle.net/xjdvngwe/

Basically I want to achieve passing an options to the chart
function at the time of chart creation

```
var options = { fill:false,tension:0, lineTension :0.1};
var chart_testChart = new Chart.Line(ctx, 
    { 
        data: data, 
        options: options 
    });
```

And in the latest version 2.1.6, I cannot get this to work

If I pass them like this, they work fine but I am looking for a way to pass them as options object

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you misunderstood how the chart is built :

You supposed that `fill` and `tension` attributes were both directly in the root of the options, but they are actually in `options.element.line`.

For more information, check the Chart.js doc about [element configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-element-configuration) (*Scroll until **Line Configuration** in your case*).

---

**But be careful !! Don't mix up :**

- Editing one element (*as you managed to do in the second part of your question*) by editing the dataset you pass to the chart data :

  ```js
  datasets: [
  {
      label: "My First dataset",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      // ...
  }]
  ```
- Editing all the elements of the same type (*here, the line chart*) by editing the chart options :

  ```js
  var options = { elements: { line: { /*options */ } } };
  ```

  As stated in the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-element-configuration) I gave above :

  > Options can be configured for four different types of elements; arc, lines, points, and rectangles. **When set, these options apply to all objects of that type unless specifically overridden by the configuration attached to a dataset**.

So make sure you actually want to edit **all** the line charts before editing these attributes directly in the options.

---

Now if you still want to edit in the options, you will have to build your `options` var like this :

```js
var options = { elements: { line: { fill: false, tension: 0.1 } } };
var chart_testChart = new Chart.Line(ctx, 
{ 
    data: data, 
    options: options 
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdnq733q/) if you want to see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation !!! I wasn't able to infer this easily by looking at the existing docs

Comment: @PuneetGupta There is a lot of information in the docs, but sometimes, it can be hard to find what you are looking for .. Glad it helped :)